# How can I know function definition in vim for C?

Tags: ctags

I have function that prototype is  `void customer(void *unusedpointer, unsigned long customernum);`

Now, I want to call this function from another file. I write this `customer(` but I forget the prototype. I can move the definition of a function using `ctags` when it is called perfectly.

But in this case what can I do when I don't call it yet?

I guess `ctags` has a functionality to do this.

Comment: use cscope or ctags

https://github.com/tracyone/t-vim

Comment: what exactly does that do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `ctags` installed then save the file(type `:w`) and regenerate the ctags by `ctags -R filename` then `<Ctrl-]>` to go to the function definition.